# The best way to Find entries missing after inner-join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Lets suppose that we have the following 3 tables

```
Animal

id name
1 dog
2 cat
3 crow


Actions

id name
1 run
2 walk
3 jump
4 fly
5 puppy_eyes
6 swim

Animal_Actions
id Animal_id action_id
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 1 3
4 1 5
5 2 1
6 2 2
7 2 3
8 3 2
9 3 4
```

I would like to find all the missing animal actions for certain animals

For example if we input dog and cat( id 1 and 2) we should get the following `(1,4),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5), (2,6)`

and if we input crow (3) we get the following `(3,1),(3,3),(3,5), (3,6)` .

Currently I'm doing an inner join between Animal and Animal_Actions table based on animal ID and importing this into a SET in my code and checking if every possible permutation is present in this set and collecting the missing ones. I'm not sure if the process I follow is the most efficient one, is there a better way to do this when the data is at a large scale ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'll be filtering on a small number of `Animal` records, one approach is to do a [CROSS JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) with the `Actions` table. That will give you all action combinations for each `Animal` record. Then do an [OUTER JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_join) to `Animal_Actions` to identify which ones are missing.

For example, using cat = 2 and dog = 1

> ```
> SELECT ani.id AS Animal_Id
>        , ani.Name AS Animal_Name
>        , act.id AS Action_Id
>        , act.Name AS Action_Name
> FROM   Animal ani
>           CROSS JOIN Actions act 
>           LEFT JOIN Animal_Actions aa ON ani.id = aa.Animal_id
>              AND aa.Action_Id = act.id
> WHERE  ani.id IN (1,2)
> AND    aa.id IS NULL
> ORDER BY ani.Name, act.Name
> ;
> ```

**Results:**

> ```
> Animal_Id | Animal_Name | Action_Id | Action_Name
> --------: | :---------- | --------: | :----------
>         2 | cat         |         4 | fly        
>         2 | cat         |         5 | puppy_eyes 
>         2 | cat         |         6 | swim       
>         1 | dog         |         4 | fly        
>         1 | dog         |         6 | swim
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16f9e8516fe6edc2cd01a21d1e9e6167)*

Comment: Thanks ! Do you think this approach would be better suited than the one I am currently following incase the number of entries is much larger in the animal table in comparison to the Actions table ? thanks again  !

Comment: It's not about total rows in the animal table, but how many *filtered* rows. In the "cat" and "dog" example, it's only 2 rows.  Generally speaking, looping tends to be the slowest method. Assuming the tables are indexed, and you're filtring for a small number of animals, a db query would likely be more efficient.